# If 2 pairs of cells are not equal, do something in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have 2 tables in Excel. The itemx, attributex in attrDICTIONARY needs to be updated based on Sheet 2.

1. I want to go through each itemx, attributex in Sheet 2
2. If it is not found in attrDICTIONARY, add a new row with the missing itemx, attributex in

Note: These columns are sorted in alphabetical order A-Z by itemx. There are also a large number of entries in Sheet 2 relative to attrDICTIONARY.

attrDICTIONARY contains:

```
column1 column2  
item1   attribute1  
item2   attribute2  
item4   attribute4
```

Sheet 2 contains:

```
column1 column2   
item1 attribute1   
item2 attribute2  
item3 attribute3  
item4 attribute4
```

I have tried this:

```
 Sub addAttributesToAttrDICTIONARY()
'
' addAttributesToAttrDICTIONARY Macro
'

    Sheet2LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    attrDictionaryLastRow = Worksheets("attrDICTIONARY").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 1

    For i = 2 To Sheet2LastRow
        While j <= attrDictionaryLastRow
incrementj:
            j = j + 1
            If (StrComp(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value, Worksheets("attrDICTIONARY").Cells(j, 2).Value)) = 0 And (StrComp(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value, Worksheets("attrDICTIONARY").Cells(j, 3).Value)) = 0 Then
                GoTo Nexti
            Else
                Worksheets("attrDICTIONARY").Rows(j).Insert
                Worksheets("attrDICTIONARY").Cells(j, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value
                Worksheets("attrDICTIONARY").Cells(j, 3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value
                attrDictionaryLastRow = attrDictionaryLastRow + 1
                GoTo Nexti
            End If
        Wend
Nexti:
    Next i

End Sub
```

Since the tables are sorted, I am just checking if they are the same, if not add a row above and add the appropriate values.

This code works up until about 4000 thousand items. At that point, it seems like the code stops checking for duplicates and just adds new rows for everything, pushing the original values down to the bottom and creating duplicates. I checked using a different coloured font for new items.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, use Long not Integer.

Comment: `j = 1` should probably be inside the `For... ` loop, just before the `While ...`

Comment: Have you run the loop and paused at 3999 and then stepped through the code at 4000 and checked the values in the line   If (StrComp(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value, Worksheets("attrDICTIONARY").Cells(j, 2).Value)) = 0 And (StrComp(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value, Worksheets("attrDICTIONARY").Cells(j, 3).Value)) = 0 Then  ?

Comment: You should envisage using references for the worksheets, to shorten the code...

Comment: @VincentG I figured since the tables are sorted, I wouldn't have to run through `attrDICTIONARY` every time I wanted to check for a new itemx, attributex in `Sheet2`

Comment: @ArbabHaque True.

Comment: @QHarr Yeah, so I printed 0 if it was a match or 1 if it wasn't. The last 0 gets printed at 3909 even though there definitely is more matches in the data. Do you think the problem could be occurring because of formatting discrepancies?

Comment: What do you mean by formatting discrepancies? I meant, if you can nail down the tipping point where behaviour differs from expected (i.e. there are more dups to find but inserts occur), have you then, at this point, inspected each of the conditions in the If to see if one, or more, is failing? Then trace any erroneous values back to their source (potentially a logic flaw for example).

Comment: @QHarr Thanks a lot, I did what you said and found that even though column1 values were sorted, column2 values were not. I have to find a way to do that.

Comment: Advanced filter on the source data?

Comment: @QHarr Good idea, I'll try that. btw, I can't accept your answer for some reason I don't see the check mark. I am new to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub addAttributesToAttrDICTIONARY()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsAttr As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim rAttr As Range
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim aAdd() As Variant
    Dim AddIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsAttr = wb.Sheets("attrDICTIONARY")
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rAttr = wsAttr.Range("B2", wsAttr.Cells(wsAttr.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    aData = wsData.Range("A2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2).Value
    ReDim aAdd(1 To 65000, 1 To UBound(aData, 2))

    For i = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rAttr.Columns(1), aData(i, 1), rAttr.Columns(2), aData(i, 2)) = 0 Then
            AddIndex = AddIndex + 1
            For j = 1 To UBound(aData, 2)
                aAdd(AddIndex, j) = aData(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

    If AddIndex > 0 Then
        rAttr.Offset(rAttr.Rows.Count).Resize(AddIndex, UBound(aAdd, 2)).Value = aAdd
        With wsAttr.Range("B2", wsAttr.Cells(wsAttr.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            .Sort .Resize(, 1), xlAscending, .Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1), , xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```